# Writing SQL queries in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

This question is mainly about the best practice of writing queries in nodejs. We had referred several tutorials, but were not able to reach a conclusion.

We have a node js API layer which is mainly used for reading and writing to database. Here is a sample code:

```
pool.query("update node SET changed = " + params.updationTime + " where nid = " + params.nid);
pool.query("update node_revision SET timestamp = " + params.updationTime +" where nid = " + params.nid);
pool.end();
```

Is this a correct way of writing code or should we write the sql queries in async format itself.

Comment: Btw. not having async calls means that the queries **will not** execute simultaniously.

Comment: no, this has nothing to do with having callback in the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pool configuration allows more than one connection then likely both queries are executed in parallel. Type of call itself does not matter. This example takes 2 seconds to finish:

```
 connection.query('select sleep(1)');
 connection.query('select sleep(1)', function() { console.log('done!') });
```

As well as this one:

```
 connection.query('select sleep(1)', function() {
   connection.query('select sleep(1)', function() { 
     console.log('done!') 
   });
  });
```

because mysql protocol itself is "sequential" (that is, client is allowed to send next query only after result of previous is fully received). Most async clients hide this limitation by queueing commands internally. In case of two connections, queries actually go in parallel:

```
 connection1.query('select sleep(1)', function() { console.log('done1') });
 connection2.query('select sleep(1)', function() { console.log('done2') });
```

"done1" and "done2" are both going to appear on screen in approximately 1 second

`pool.query` is a shorlcut for `pool.getConnection()` + `connection.query()` + `connection.release()` - see [readme](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#pooling-connections)

Comment: Which one is the most appropriate way of writing queries (Best practice).
The first method or the second method?In our code currently we are using the first method.

Comment: If queries unrelated - first method (but still with error handling). If related - second one

Answer (score 0):

When writing SQL queries in NodeJS, I cannot promote [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) enough!

- **Programatic way to build dynamic queries.** (writing dynamic raw SQL strings is a very manual process)
- Connection pools.
- Transaction support.
- String escaping.
- And on and on.

For your specific question, you just make the queries and execute them (using callbacks or Promises), the Knex connection pool will handle all the pooling, and generally things will just work for you.

You'll like it, give it a try : )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use sails.js (http://sailsjs.org/#/) framework, which uses Waterline Query Language(http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Querylanguage.html) to retrieve data from mySQL/mongodb/Redis database.